# Removing Gmail app for guest device in my home

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, media-player, kiosk-mode

I recently picked up an HTC One V phone for practically free. I want to use it as a "media device" in my home. I have it hooked up to a dock and would like to have Netflix/Pandora/Play Music (linked to my personal Google account) installed. Since I frequently have guests in my home, I do not want ANY access to my personal things. (GMail and Play Store).  What is the safest way to remove access to Gmail and the Play Store (or to force password entry every time), while allowing full access to my Play Music without a password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a so called "App Locker" like e.g. [App Lock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock), which allow you to protect selected apps with a pattern lock. A more restrictive way would be to turn your tab into a "Kiosk device" (details can be found following the [kiosk-mode](/questions/tagged/kiosk-mode) tag; just 6 questions, so it should be easy to browse).